# Azure Windows Nano VM VMAgent not installed cannot RDP

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, rdp

I've created an Azure Free Trial subscription intending to migrate an existing web site that uses Classic ASP and SQL. After creating a VM with Windows Nano and pretty much accepting the defaults, besides providing names as needed, I cannot RDP to the new server.

I've followed most every step-by-step that I could find over the last 3 days, but still not any closer to being able to RDP into the server. Some interesting observations working in the Azure Portal VM-Diagnose/Solve Problems:
1. The console screenshot appears, but is all black
2. Verify IP Flow says Access Allowed when tested. RDP, HTTP, HTTPS, FTP ports all verify Allowed
3. NSG rules all indicate Allowed
4. PowerShell commands are where it gets interesting. Some suggested commands execute with no problem. Others error when executed.

What appears to be one major problem is the VMAgent and Extension
My first VM creation failed to provision the Extension. Reset Configuration Only never completed the process and failed repeatedly. Redeploy didn't correct the problem either. I deleted that server and all the resources to start fresh. One note of interest, I was able to reset the password using the portal commands.

The second and third attempts never got a VMAgent or Extension. All attempts at creating one using the Portal and PowerShell have failed. The result of attempting to create them sets the server into an never ending loop of install.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated. It seems so simple in the demo videos, but I'm several days into this and not any closer to a solution.

Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Azure Support and they informed me that Windows Nano does not support RDP and recommended selecting another OS. I created a Windows 2016 Datacenter VM that allows me to RDP without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to view the extension status from the portal as below?

[image]

**If no** then you can install the extensions using PowerShell.

Set-AzureRmVMAccessExtension -ResourceGroupName  -VMName "Name of the VM" -Name "Name of the extension" -UserName "RDP UserName" -Password "Secure Password"

Comment: Thanks for the response and suggestion. I didn't see any extensions in the portal. I used your suggested Powershell command and created an extension that is now listed in the portal and indicates Provisioning Complete. However, I'm still not able to RDP to the server even after restarting it. The Health Check says nothing is wrong and Verify IP Flow test says "Allowed" using port 3389 both Inbound and Outbound directions within the portal. RDP error: 1) Remote access to the server is not enabled 2) The remote computer is turned off 3) The remote computer is not available on the network.

Comment: Thought I would add: My machine has no issue with RDP to a VM on AWS. I would like to migrate to Azure BUT using up my $200 free trial just trying to RDP to a brand new VM is making it a hard sell. Thank you in advance for any further suggestions.